# Inner Join with table object

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I want to create an inner join of the following query

```
select listmybill.tid from listmybill  
inner join
Trainerdetails
on 
listmybill.tid=Trainerdetails.tid
```

this is working very good but i want to create the object of these table in this inner join like

```
select l.tid from listmybill  as l.listmybill
inner join
Trainerdetails as t.Trainerdetails
on 
l.tid=T.tid
```

but i am getting the error of incorrect syntax

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '.'.

how can i create a proc like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select l.tid 
from listmybill  as l
inner join Trainerdetails as t on l.tid=T.tid
```